# My Node.js HTTP proxy server crash on connResetException

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I have implemented a HTTP-proxy server app in Node.js, using the `http-proxy` module.

Occasionally the App crashes and according to the logfile it seems like it is caused by a connection reset exception, thrown by the http-proxy module

Logile:

```
2021-11-01T12:50:57.006759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-01T12:50:57.046446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840974+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:120
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840981+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840982+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840982+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840983+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: socket hang up
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840983+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840983+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:401:25)
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:326:22)
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:675:12
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840985+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:568:7) {
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840985+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ECONNRESET'
2021-11-01T12:50:56.840985+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-11-01T12:50:56.849770+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-11-01T12:50:56.849910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-11-01T12:50:56.852684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! dexautheu@1.0.0 start: `node dexAuthEU.js`
2021-11-01T12:50:56.852724+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-11-01T12:50:56.852780+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-11-01T12:50:56.852819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the dexautheu@1.0.0 start script.
2021-11-01T12:50:56.852853+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-11-01T12:50:56.861038+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-11-01T12:50:56.861180+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-11-01T12:50:56.861228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-11-01T12_50_56_853Z-debug.log
```

I am quite new to java script but I recon that I need to catch this exception in my code and handle it, but the problem is I really don't know where in my app I should put it. I already use try/catch to handle exceptions from the JSON parser. Here is a sample of my app:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const port = process.env.PORT;

var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
 
  target: '<target-server>',
  secure: false,
  followRedirects: true,
  autoRewrite: true,
  changeOrigin: true,
  selfHandleResponse: true
}).listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
 });
 
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    var Account = '';
    Account = proxyReq.getHeader('account');
    console.log('Request from: ', Account); 
});
 
proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        
        var body = '';
        var response = '';
        proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        proxyRes.on('end', function () {
 
            try {
                response = JSON.parse(body);
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('Code')) {
                    console.log('Error Message: ', JSON.stringify(response['Code']));
                    if (response['Code'] == 'SSO_AuthenticateAccountNotFound' || response['Code'] == 'SSO_AuthenticatePasswordInvalid') {
                        res.writeHead(401);
                        res.end(JSON.stringify({SessionID: '', ErrorMsg : response['Code'], ErrorCode : 401}));
                    }
                } else { 
                    console.log('SessionID: ', response);
                    res.end(JSON.stringify({SessionID : response, ErrorMsg : 'OK', ErrorCode: 200}));
                }
            
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log('JSON error: ' , error);    
                
            }
            
        });
    });
```

I saw an example somewhere in which they defined the error handling here:

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
     
      target: '<target-server>',
      secure: false,
      followRedirects: true,
      autoRewrite: true,
      changeOrigin: true,
      selfHandleResponse: true
    }).listen(port, function(err) {
      if (err) {
         console.log('Error serving https proxy request: %s', req);
      }
      console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
    });
```

Would this be an appropriate solution? Or should I have a different strategy? Thank you in advance.